# Efficient way to create a list a list from class variable. (multiple lists)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Which example would be faster?

Example 1

```
A = [] 
B = [] 
C = [] 

for i in range(x, y): 
    A.append(obj[i].a) 
    B.append(obj[i].b) 
    C.append(obj[i].c)
```

Example 2

```
A = [obj[i].a for i in range(x, y)]
B = [obj[i].b for i in range(x, y)] 
C = [obj[i].c for i in range(x, y)]
```

Comment: Since you have both codes, figuring out which is faster is as easy as trying it yourself. Why not do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first one:

- complexity of the first one is `O(n)`
- complexity of the second one is `O(3n)`